# What is $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\frac{p_{m+1}}{p_m}|m\in \mathbb{N},m\geq n\right\} $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is 
$$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\frac{p_{m+1}}{p_m}\middle|m\in \mathbb{N},m\geq n\right\} = ?$$
where $p_i$ is i'th prime number.
We know that this limsup exists because of [bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) that says for every natural number $n>1$ there exists a prime like $p$ that $n<p<2n$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: i think if it exists, it should be less than $2$.

Comment: @AhaanRungta maybe it's value be 1, but this is just a conjecture.

Comment: @cand because of bertrand's postulate the sets are bounded by 2 from above, thus limsup exists.

Comment: @cand yes the answer will be greater than or equal $1$ and less than or equal $2$.

Comment: Since the distribution of primes is more "dense" than that of squares, and the limsup of the corresponding quotient of consecutive squares is 1, I'd guess your limit is also 1.

Comment: @TheSubstitute: it is known that your guess holds when one substitutes "cubes" in place of "squares". However, the Landau conjecture on primes between squares is still a conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is always a prime between two consecutive, big enough, cubes (Ingham's theorem - it is quite an advanced result that goes in the direction of proving that there is always a prime between two consecutive squares, that is still a conjecture) such $\limsup$ is just one.

However, the fact that $p_{n+1}-p_n=o(p_n)$ dates back to $1896$ (year of first proof of the PNT by Hadamard and, indipendently, de la Vallée-Poussin), or to $1949$, when Erdos and Selberg found their brilliant elementary proof.

This because for any constant $c>1$, the PNT shows that $\pi(cn)-\pi(n)$ is eventually positive, hence that $\limsup$ is less or equal to $c$ for any $c>1$. Since it is obviously greater or equal to $1$, it is just one.

Comment: Doesn't it date back to the 1890s when the PNT was first established?

Comment: No, because the PNT in itself is not enough to prove that such limsup is one, but the Selberg's formula is enough.

Comment: I disagree: the PNT by itself establishes that, for instance, $\pi(1.0001n) - \pi(n) \to \infty$ (in particular it's eventually positive), so that the limsup cannot be greater than $1.0001$.

Comment: That does not prove, however, that the limsup is one.

Comment: Really?  Which of the three options of "limsup < 1", "limsup > 1", "limsup does not exist" remains?

Comment: The point was that the proof of Erdős was elementary. The result follows from PNT.

Comment: @ErickWong: Ok, I'm convinced you are right, I'm updating my answer.